# Is it possible to run an Akka cluster with only one single node, while using Akka Cluster Bootstrap and Discovery from Config?

Tags: akka-cluster

I'm developing a service by using "Akka Cluster" as my main toolkit and I'm using "Akka Cluster Bootstrap" via "discovery from config" to bootstrap it. But It didn't work in the way that I expected.

Right now it needs all participating nodes (defined in `akka.discovery.config.services`) to be up and running. In other words, it won't start a cluster until all of them became available. However, I need to bootstrap the cluster even when only one of them is running.

I've configured `required-contact-point-nr = 1` but nothing changed.

How I can configure it to start the cluster with minimum available nodes?

Answer (score 0):

If the respective single node you start is listed in the `akka.discovery.config.services.[YourActorSystemName].endpoints`, then

```
required-contact-point-nr = 1
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A cluster start requires all nodes to be available, else the gossip can't converge.

required-contact-point-nr is just about contact point discovery, the actual cluster bootstrap requires all nodes to be there. Nodes can join / leave later after a bootstrap, but the bootstrap itself requires all nodes to be there.